# Error -"Could not drop constraint" when execute .AsQueryable();

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, many-to-many

I am using EF code first to generate many to many relation. as the following:

```
public  class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Categories = new Collection<Category>();
    }
    public  int UserId { get; set; }
    public  string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
 public sealed class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        Users = new Collection<User>();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

}
```

My Db context look like:

```
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(b => b.Categories).WithMany(a => a.Users).Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("userId").MapRightKey("id"));

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

The weird issue is when Im doing simple action like:

```
_ctx.Categories.AsQueryable();
```

I get the following error:

> The constraint 'PK_dbo.Categories' is being referenced by table 'UserCategories', foreign key constraint 'FK_dbo.CategoryUsers_dbo.Categories_id'.
>   Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.